# Retrieve raw jwt token value in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, openid, jwt

I'd like to retrieve the raw value of the jwt token from an authorized request. I know it's the source for all the claims, but I have a use case for needing the original raw value. Is there any way to retrieve it? In case it depends on the authentication type, we're using OpenIdConnect (scheme = Oidc).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on you setup, you may simply be able to to grab the access token from the Authorization Header. Example:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
[HttpGet("GetStuff")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetStuff()
{
   var access_token = HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
}
```

In Core 2.0, the AuthenticationManager class in ycrumeyrolle's answer has been marked obsolete.  You can substitute this line of code:

```
var token = await AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.GetTokenAsync(HttpContext, "<name_of_signin_scheme>", "access_token");
```

Answer (score 1):

Although it's an old question, I found myself searching for a way to do this on .NET 7.
This is one way to get access to the raw Bearer (JWT) token passed on a request:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [TestController]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public TestController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetSomethingAsync()
        {
            StringValues authHeaders = string.Empty;

            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request.Headers
                .TryGetValue("Authorization", out authHeaders);

            var tokenAsRawString = authHeaders.ToString();

            // do something with token
            ...
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with raw? The token itself is raw, is just a base64 of the token itself. If you put the token on [jwt.io](http://jwt.io), you can always decode it, it's not a secret stuff.

If you think you need the raw token because you need some of the values it have inside itself, the best thing to do is to add a copy of those element to the authorization response, as additional items.

Comment: Actually what I need to do is extract the token from the user's incoming request and forward it in outbound requests from the server to downstream services.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
// add JWT authentication (change to OIDC if you prefer)
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions 
{ 
   StoreToken = true       
}); 


// then in your code...
var rawToken = await authenticationManager.GetTokenAsync("<name_of_signin_scheme>", "access_token");
```

The drawback is that the token will be stored in the properties then in an authentication cookie, if any.

Otherwise, you can get the raw token with the ReceivedToken event.

The GetTokenAsync() method can be found in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication, in the namespace of the same name.

Comment: What is the type of the `authenticationManager` object? And is `GetTokenAsync` an extension method? I'm looking at `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication.AuthenticationManager`, and I'm not seeing that method.

Comment: It's an extension method indeed, just found it in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationTokenExtensions`. Let me give it a try, if this works I'll accept your answer.

Comment: What package / namespace do I need to add to access that extension method? I tried adding `Microsoft.AspNet.Security`, but I still don't have the `Microsoft.AspNetCore` namespace (let alone any of its sub-namespaces).

Comment: I found it, it's not available in the most recent RC1 release. It was added afterwards and has yet to be released in a stable build.

Comment: The raw token should also be available in the ClaimsIdentity.BootstrapContext.

Answer (score 0):

There is a short blog post about exactly this issue: http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/aspnetcore-jwt-saving-bearer-token-as-claim/

You can either save the token in the `AuthenticationProperties` (see also the answer of @ycrumeyrolle). or you save the token as a claim in the `OnTokenValidated` callback. This is set up in the `JwtBearerOptions`. Please see the linked article for all the details.